# Split/Slicing in Python 3 three different string arrays

Tags: python-3.x, split, slice

Code

```
def clouds_function():
    """
    Extracts Cloud Height and Type from the data 
    Returns: Cloud Height and Type CCCXXX
    """ 
    clouds1 = content[1]
    clouds1 = clouds1[15:len(clouds1)]
    clouds1 = clouds1.split()

    clouds2 = content[2]
    clouds2 = clouds2 + "  "
    clouds2=[clouds2[y-8:y] for y in range(8, len(clouds2)+8,8)]

    clouds3 = content[3]
    clouds3 = clouds3 + "  "
    print(clouds3)
    clouds3=[clouds3[y-8:y] for y in range(8, len(clouds3)+8,8)]

    return(clouds3)

print(clouds_function())
```

Sample Data

```
content[1] = 'OVC018  BKN006  OVC006  OVC006  OVC017  OVC005  OVC005 OVC016  OVC029  OVC003  OVC002  OVC001  OVC100'
content[2] ='         OVC025                          OVC010  OVC009                                         OVC200'
content[3] ='         OVC100                                       '
```

I tried

```
def split(s, n):
    if len(s) < n:
        return []
    else:
        return [s[:n]] + split(s[n:], n)
```

It returns `['OVC100  ']` for `content[3]`

I need

```
['','OVC100','','','','','','','','','','','']
```

The results

```
(['OVC018', 'BKN006', 'OVC006', 'OVC006', 'OVC017', 'OVC005', 'OVC005', 'OVC016', 'OVC029', 'OVC003', 'OVC002', 'OVC001', 'OVC100'], ['OVC025  ', '        ', '        ', '        ', 'OVC010  ', 'OVC009  ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '     ', 'OVC200  '], ['OVC100  '])
```

I need homogeneous arrays

It might be a problem with each being a uneven length to begin with so still.

Comment: why is there only one space between `OVC005 OVC016` ? why are `content[2]` and  `3` 1 char longer before the 2nd element `[1] = 'OVC018.BKN006` vs `[2] ='.........OVC025` ? Copy&paste error or data inadequaties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has lenght-problems and different gap-sizes (2 or 1 character):

> ```
> c[1] = 'OVC018  BKN006  OVC006  OVC006  OVC017  OVC005  OVC005 OVC016  OVC029  OVC003  OVC002  OVC001  OVC100'
> c[2] ='         OVC025                          OVC010  OVC009                                         OVC200'
> c[3] ='         OVC100                                       '
> ```

- `c[2]` and `c[3]` use 9 characters to the start of the 2nd value, `c[1]` only 8
- between `'OVC005 OVC016'` is only 1 space, normally 2
- c[3] is much shorter then the others

Slicing is good if you have constant or predictable lengths (you haven't) - this can be better solved using simple string addition and replacements of space-streches by a character used to split it afterwards:

1. make all strings equally long - filling up with spaces
2. replace all [8,7,6,2,1] long stretches of spaces by `'-'` - a (new) artificial splitter character
3. split at `'-'`

---

```
content= ['OVC018  BKN006  OVC006  OVC006  OVC017  OVC005  OVC005 OVC016  OVC029  OVC003  OVC002  OVC001  OVC100',
          '        OVC025                          OVC010  OVC009                                         OVC200',
          '        OVC100                                       ']

# extend data 
max_len = max(len(data) for data in content)

for i,c in enumerate(content):
    # fix legths 
    content[i] = c + " " * (max_len-len(c))
    # replace stretches of spaces by a splitter character
    content[i] = content[i].replace(" "*8,"-").replace(" "*7,"-").replace(" "*6,"-").replace("  ","-").replace(" ","-")


hom = [c.split("-") for c in content]
for c in hom:
    print(c,"\n")
```

Output:

```
['OVC018', 'BKN006', 'OVC006', 'OVC006', 'OVC017', 'OVC005', 'OVC005', 'OVC016', 'OVC029', 'OVC003', 'OVC002', 'OVC001', 'OVC100']

['', 'OVC025', '', '', '', 'OVC010', 'OVC009', '', '', '', '', '', 'OVC200']

['', 'OVC100', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```